# Since KB2898785 IE6 doesn't load locally-sourced CSS for a page delivered remotely--how to correct?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

First of all, I wish the CSS and images could come over the wire, but network performance is slow and these are kiosks.  The images and CSS live on the hard drive, while the page content comes over the wire.

Prior to [KB2898785](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2898785), we made it work by allowing cross-domain and local active content in IE6 (don't ask why IE6--it just is), and now we can't seem to get the CSS to load at all.  I've run out of ideas on how to address this, and the customer isn't happy with bringing the visuals in off the wire.

Can anyone think of a workaround?

Comment: In seriousness, I'm sure it would actually be a LOT less work to upgrade to IE8 (the highest version you can get on XP) than it would be to get IE6 to work.

Comment: How are you including the CSS? What are your symptoms? Can you give us a minimal reproducing example? Are you loading the local CSS from a file, or from a locally-running web server? Anything in the IE console, or any other logs? Also: have you considered getting a new job? Nobody should [still have to be dealing with IE6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruel_and_unusual_punishment).

Comment: 1 & 2) Can't stop using IE6.  I'd love to, but there's an actual industry spec we have to follow and it says IE6.

Comment: 3) Can't really show anything without compromising IP.  The CSS is loaded via file reference, as the kiosks don't have IIS (or any other web server) on them due to memory constraints.  (While I appreciate the political commentary on IE6 to a certain extent, it ain't solving the problem, folks.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install some kind of webserver on the local machine and have it serve the CSS?

Comment: We might be able to craft up a Civet build to do it.  That might be small enough to run in the available memory.  I'll investigate that.